# Issue with Smo .EnumAvailableMedia()

Tags: c#, smo

I'm creating a folder browser dialog from a remote sql machine.

Been using this as template. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576995/folder-browser-dialog-from-remote-machine-perspective-like-the-one-ssms-uses/21892091#21892091)

My problem is .EnumAvailableMedia() is not returning any results. I'm getting a successful connection to the server. Have tried multiple servers, both 2008 and 2014.

Thanks in advance!

```
Server server = new Server(fullServerName);

DataTable dt = server.EnumAvailableMedia();
dt = server.EnumAvailableMedia();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   treeListDir.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(row["Name"].ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Are you connecting to it with an account with sufficient privileges?  Also, IIRC, if the windows account the SQL service is running under does not have sufficient rights within the host , then the [sa] SQL account will not be able to enumerate them either.  In other words, maybe there's no media visible to whatever security context you are using?

Comment: I have attempted this one two different type of Authentications, both windows authentication and sql server authentications (on two different sql servers on the network) and was not successful on either one. Using a different application with almost the same logic (albeit in c++) does however produce results.

Comment: Can you show us the C++ code?  We should be able to figure out the difference then.

Comment: So I discovered that SMO EnumAvailableMedia is in fact working, there is just a second layer needed to get through the data-table to actually get the folders. 

Once the drives are received, calling this on each drive will receive another data-table full of directories. 

DataTable dirTable = srv.EnumDirectories(drive);